# Kubernetes: Split workloads which don't declare resources into separate NodePool, at NodePool level

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We are working on solving a problem where there are applications which don't have declared resources i.e Requests+limits. To stop them from effecting good deployments, we have decided temporarily to move them to a separate NodePool, but not at the application/deployment level.

We just want to create a new NodePool, where the parameters are configured as such that it will only accept Pods which don't have/or partial resource declaration.

Is there any way to do this in Kubernetes at NodePool level.

Note that we are using Terraform for creating Nodepools in GKE.

Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use mutating web hook to perform this.Where in when you deploy your manifest check if the resources section is defined or not and then add node selector in cases where don't find resource section defined.